# Generating Enum array of integer length

Tags: c++, enums

In C++, or more specifically unreal engine Ufunction, I need to create an Enum array based on an integer. (my output is based on Enum so there is no other way as far as I know.)

While I do have basic coding knowledge, I'm relatively new to C++. Enums are new to me and it might be that I misunderstand the nature of Enums.

The array would be empty at first, and needs to be filled up to contain N members based on my integer input. What method do I use to approach this issue?

The output would look like this:

```
enum class myEnum : uint8{
    Enum1,
    Enum2,
    Enum3,
    Enum4,
    Enum5,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can update an array with elements at runtime (because it is simply data), enums specify a type and type definitions MUST be resolvable at compile time (which is a good thing!). So there's no straightforward way to achieve your expectation.

One suggestion would be to use std::set, which is quite similar to an enum functionally and also provides methods to manipulate it later on, which could be beneficial for your use case.

Comment: Well I need to be able to edit it in the editor. I can compile it after I got my output but I don't want to have to go into my code just to add an Enum while I just want to be able to add 1 to my integer

Answer (score 0):

Enum is your own data type and it's based on int. See the code below:

```
enum YOUR_ENUM
{
    YOUR_AGE = 20,          //assigned 20 by programmer
    YEAR = 2019,            //assigned 2019 by programmer
    NEXT_YEAR,              //assigned 2020 by compiler
    NEXT_NEXT_YEAR          //assigned 2021 by compiler
};

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << YOUR_AGE << endl;
    cout << YEAR << endl;
    cout << NEXT_YEAR << endl;
    cout << NEXT_NEXT_YEAR << endl;
}
```